# Wrong XML Comments in Code-View

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

It seems there is a bug in the XML-Code-Viewer in StackOverflow:

See the related post:
[doFilter HttpServletRequest return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945493/dofilter-httpservletrequest-return-null)

In XML comments are made by

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

Apparently there are no other variants (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17327140/2516892)

Yet `/* Comment */` seems to be accepted as well (as seen in the first link).

As tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OuterTag>
    <ToUseForWhichFiles>/*</ToUseForWhichFiles>
    <AndThisIsJustHere>To Show You </AndThisIsJustHere>
    <TheseAinT>No Comments Not</TheseAinT>
    <JustToConfuse>*/</JustToConfuse>
</OuterTag>
```

But I can't see right now how this is accepted in this code-editor...

Edit: 
As seen in some trials I was too exact and declared the XML as supposed to be. Also let's see what happens if I add some random Java-Code before it...

```
java.java




/**
 *
 * @author qohelet
 */

    final private stuff;


    public DummyJava() {
int useless = 0;
    }

public void doNothing(int useless){
        System.out.println(useless+" is useless");
}
```

And the next file:

```
<OuterTag>
    <ToUseForWhichFiles>/*</ToUseForWhichFiles>
    <AndThisIsJustHere>To Show You </AndThisIsJustHere>
    <TheseAinT>No Comments Not</TheseAinT>
    <JustToConfuse>*/</JustToConfuse>
</OuterTag>
```

Comment: Did it!!! (Java was not available, I used Javascript instead (uah...)). I successfully reproduced the bug! =)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't have enough reputation to add a Java-Tag. C/C++ was seemingly not available too... What else should I have done...?

Comment: Add JavaScript as a tag and you can reproduce the bug... Now, as no language is selected no code is shown

Comment: There is no bug. See my answer.

Comment: I noticed it, but keep JavaScript as a tag and see what happens...

Comment: See my answer again please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the XML syntax highlighting but the Java syntax highlighting used on the post.

Since the Java tag forces the post's code to be rendered as Java, not as XML, you see that it renders the XML in the post as Java code.

Putting a language element on it will fix it. Also there is a slight indentation problem (which you fixed yourself now). That didn't recognize the XML as XML too.

Adding both the extra space and the language element fixes it.

Sample:

```java
public DummyJava() { }
```

```xml
<OuterTag>abc</OuterTag>
```

Which is:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

    public DummyJava() { }

<!-- language: xml -->

    <OuterTag>abc</OuterTag>
```

Comment: I tried a bit myself. The issue was apparently The `<?xml`-Part and the `<!DOCTYPE ` weren't set properly as code. Unfortunately I had to edit half of the posting since StackOverflow doesn't accept it if I just highlight code...